# PHP - Pars Excel and explode a string by commas

Tags: php, regex, excel, parsing, split

I'm parsing an Excel file by [PHPExcel](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/). The Excel file has two columns A and B. As follows:

```
________________________
|     A     |     B    |
________________________
| 987654321 | 55,12,11 |
| 789456123 |   1,2,3  |
| 998877665 | 10,11,12 |
| 112233345 |     8    |
________________________
```

PHPExcel output is as follows for `$array1`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => "987654321","55,12,11"
    [1] => "789456123","1,2,3"
    [2] => "998877665","10,11,12"
    [3] => "112233345","8"
)
```

I use this code to parse `$array1`:

```
$res = array();
foreach ($array1 as $key => $value)
{
   if ($arr != '')
   {
      $res[$key] = explode(",", str_replace('"', '', $value));
   }
}
```

I want to get this result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 987654321
            [1] => 55,12,11
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 789456123
            [1] => 1,2,3
        )
) //etc...
```

But instead I get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 987654321
            [1] => 55
            [2] => 12
            [3] => 11
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 789456123
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 3
        )
) //etc..
```

How can I conclude?

Comment: …why are you using `explode()` if you don't want to explode `$value`?

Comment: @Chris `$value` has two parts. I just want the first part and the second part will be separated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Treat it as CSV as that's how it's coming from Excel:

```
foreach($array1 as $key => $value) {
    $res[$key] = str_getcsv($value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$res[$key] = explode('","', trim($value, '"'));
```

Note that parsing comma delimited sections like this will fail as soon as you are trying to separate strings instead of integers.